# can't call ifstream in a separate function

Tags: c++, ifstream, c++03

I am learning filestreams. I have a problem while using ifstream in a separate function outside main. Inside main it works just fine. the function is such,

```
void counter(string str)
 {
    ifstream inpufile(str,ios::in);//the error is here, it says the function cannot be called!?!
    if(!inpufile)
    {
        cout<<"\n The file does not exist, try again";
    }
    else
    {
        char c;
        int counter=0;
        while(inpufile.get(c))
        {
            if(c=='\n')
                counter++;
        }
        cout<<"\n The number of lines in the file are "<<counter+1;
    }
    inpufile.close();
 }
```

The function call is from main() and is such

```
counter(argv[1]);
```

Can I only pass ifstream as an object. Can I not create one outside main?

Comment: Do you have `#include <fstream>` in the file with the code for `counter`?

Comment: yeah, I did. Its on top of the file.

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with your code.  Do you get a compilation error, or runtime error?

Comment: A compilation error. CodeBlocks 13.12, if that is of any help

Comment: @Sam: Which editor makes very little difference.  It's the compiler version, and compile options, that are important.  Code::Blocks is an editor not a compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem doesn't have anything to do with the function, it has to do with the variable holding the filename.  Consider:

```
int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    std::ifstream inpufile(argv[1], ios::in); // ok

    std::string fname = argv[1]; // ok
    std::ifstream fileb(str, ios::in); // fails pre-C++11
}
```

By having a function, you're causing an implicit conversion from `const char*` to `std::string`, just like in the example above.  And `std::fstream` didn't take `std::string` for the filename until C++11.  Two ways to fix:

```
void counter(const char* fname)
{
    ifstream inpufile(fname, ios::in); // works now
```

and `counter(argv[1]);` still works, in fact it works a tiny bit better because no conversion is needed.

Or

```
void counter(std::string fname)
{
    ifstream inpufile(str.c_str(), ios::in); // ok too
```

Which gets the `const char*` that `fstream` expects.

C++11 does finally fix this and let you use `std::string` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create it inside a function. The function is correct.

In case (before C++11) you need to turn `std::string` to `char*`, you can use `c_str()`.

So change this:

`ifstream inpufile(str,ios::in);`

to this:

`ifstream inpufile(str.c_str(),ios::in);`

You could do it like this:

```
void counter(string str, ifstream& inpufile) {
  if (!inpufile) {
    cout << "\n The file does not exist, try again";
  } else {
    char c;
    int counter = 0;
    while (inpufile.get(c)) {
      if (c == '\n')
        counter++;
    }
    cout << "\n The number of lines in the file are " << counter + 1;
  }
  inpufile.close();
}

int main() {
  string str = "Team.txt";
  ifstream inpufile(str.c_str(), ios::in);
  counter(str, inpufile);
  return 0;
}
```

You could also create the file object in main and open it inside the function like this:

```
void counter(string str, ifstream& inpufile) {
  inpufile.open(str.c_str(), ios::in);
  if (!inpufile) {
    cout << "\n The file does not exist, try again";
  } else {
    char c;
    int counter = 0;
    while (inpufile.get(c)) {
      if (c == '\n')
        counter++;
    }
    cout << "\n The number of lines in the file are " << counter + 1;
  }
  inpufile.close();
}

int main() {
  string str = "Team.txt";
  ifstream inpufile;
  counter(str, inpufile);
  return 0;
}
```

Your code feeds the function with the filename and then creates the file object inside the function.

Comment: That is precisely my question, can I not just pass a file name and create an ifstream object outside main()?

Comment: Yes you can @SamEbenezer, isn't that what the code in my answer does? Oh, maybe you want to create the file object outside and then inside the function feed it with the filename?

Comment: No, feed the function with the filename and then create the file object inside the function.

Comment: This is exactly what your function does @SamEbenezer, am I wrong?

Comment: yeah, but I cant get it to work, it says at line 3 that "no matching function to call std::basic_ifstream"

Comment: You are probably not using C++11. Check my update. You need to use `.c_str()` which converts a std::string to a C string. @SamEbenezer

Answer (score 1):

```
ifstream inpufile(str.c_str());
```

`ios::in` isn't necessary as it's implicitly set.

Comment: This answer has been flagged for quality review because it is a 'code only' answer.

Comment: @EngineerDollery there's one sentence in English in it. Hopefully you don't believe English sentences are code, and don't suffer from some kind of syndrome where you cannot read past the first line of anything. Barring both of those scenarios, you should be more careful with your flags in the future.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes -- I didn't flag it for quality review; it just appeared in the list of things to review. I flagged the answer as ok, but thought that leaving a nice comment about the fact that this was flagged might help the poster be a little more verbose like the answers above. Also, technically, that's not a sentence -- it's a random collection of words that can't be called a sentence when used in that way -- I mean, have you read it? It doesn't make any sense (to me) -- though that wasn't my original point.

Comment: Ugh. "be a little more verbose". Use as many words as necessary to deliver the answer, no more than that.

Comment: @EngineerDollery Fair enough, then. `ios::in` is the subject; "isn't" is the verb; "necessary" is an adjective. Does that help making sense of it? I grant you that the rest could have been made a separate sentence starting with "it is", though.

Comment: I profusely apologize in case I offended anyone. I also added another two words.

Comment: It's ok, myself and other members of the grammar police will let this one slide this time :)